# Fancybox gallery not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a staff member page that is constructed with each member's photo and name incased in a div. When the staff members photos is clicked, it opens up a lightbox and displays their photo and bio. I have the "rel" set to "fancybox-gallery" for each photo.

When you open any photo lightbox on the page, you are presented with the "Next" arrow link. Clicking it will take you to the next staff member's lightbox where there are both "next" and "previous" arrow links. Clicking either of these links causes those links and the "close" link do disappear and the lightbox will not advance.

I'm clueless as to why this would be happening. Here's an example of one of my staff member divs.

```
<div class="staff-member even ">
<div class="staff-summary">
<div class="staff-thumb">
<a id="inline" class="fancybox-inline" rel="fancybox-gallery" href="#lacy-arant">
<img class="staff-member-photo" src="http://midtownpilates.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/MidtownPilates-Lacy.jpg">
</a>
</div>
<div class="staff-member-info-wrap">
<h3>
<a id="inline" class="fancybox-inline" href="#lacy-arant">Lacy Arant</a>
</h3>
<p class="staff-position">Owner + Instructor</p>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
<div id="lacy-arant" class="staff-full" style="width:760px;max-width:100%">
<img class="staff-member-photo" src="http://midtownpilates.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/MidtownPilates-Lacy.jpg">
<h1>Lacy Arant</h1>
<p class="staff-position">Owner + Instructor</p>
<a class="staff-member-email" title="Email Lacy Arant" href="mailto:"></a>
Lacy is the reason we have Midtown Pilates today! As a graduate of Mississippi State University, it was Lacy’s dream to bring a new, fun, functional fitness resource to the Starkville community. Lacy received her training from Pilates Academy International in NYC, and holds certifications in mat, barre, reformer, cadillac, chair, barrels, cardiolates, and pre- and post-natal therapy. She now trains all of our instructors right here in Starkville! Lacy has a passion for health and fitness, as well as for the people of Starkville which is apparent in her personal teaching style. You’ll rarely see Lacy without an MP Glow spray tan and a dark magenta lipstick on her lips! Lacy recently got married to Stephen in November 2014, and just adopted the second of their two puppy children.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions as to why this functionality would be working this way? This is a Wordpress site where I'm using Easy Fancybox plugin and Simple Staff List plugin to create this page.

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 0):

Author of the Easy Fancybox plugin just offered a beta version that solved this problem, as the current version didn't support inline content. That new beta version will hopefully be released to the public soon.

Keith